# “Depuis” and “depuis que” versus “il y a” and “il y a … que”

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, prépositions, indications-de-temps, constructions

I understand how to use these four expressions:

- *Depuis*
- *Depuis que*
- *Il y a* — in the temporal sense
- *Il y a … que*

I also understand the grammatical implications, but I do not understand the semantic differences between the four, and mainly between using *depuis* and *il y a*.

**My Question:**

What is the semantic difference between these expressions?  If examples could be given for the sake of providing context, semantic explanation, and perhaps even a *general usage guideline* (i.e. what type of practical situation warrants the use of one versus another), I would find this to be the most useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Il y a* and *depuis* have different meanings. *Depuis* refers to a situation that has been true since a certain time in the past (past continuous), whereas *il y a* refers to a specific time in the past (past perfect). There is a similar distinction in English: *depuis* = since, *il y a* = ago.

> Depuis une semaine, il n'a pas neigé. *It hasn't snowed for a week.*
>   Depuis une semaine, il neige. *It has been snowing for a week.*
>   Il y a une semaine, il a neigé. *It snowed a week ago.*

When *depuis* is followed by a time interval, it can be combined with *il y a* (“*depuis il y a une semaine*”), but *il y a* is frequently omitted.

*Depuis* can also be followed by an event (“*depuis son départ*”, “*depuis qu'il est parti*”). *Il y a* can only be followed by an interval, some other preposition must be used to refer to an event (“*lors de son départ*”, “*lorsqu'il est parti*”).

Comment: Sans oublier le piège qu'affectionnait particulièrement mon prof d'anglais au lycée: _il y a longtemps que je t'aime_