# It's 10 years ago that we got married

Tags: indications-de-temps

Je me demande comment on traduit la phrase qui apparaît dans le titre.

Je sais comment dire "I've been married for 10 years":

- *Je suis marié depuis 10 ans* ; ou bien
- *Il y a 10 ans que je suis marié*.

(Ces phrases sont décrites ici: [“Depuis” and “depuis que” versus “il y a” and “il y a … que”](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6910/depuis-and-depuis-que-versus-il-y-a-and-il-y-a-que))

Mais comment traduire la phrase qui apparaît dans le titre ? (Je veux souligner le fait qu'il s'agit d'une action terminée qui a eu lieu il y a quelque temps.)

- *Il y a 10 ans depuis que nous nous sommes mariés* ?
- *Il y a 10 ans que nous nous sommes mariés* ?

Merci beaucoup pour vos réponses et explications !

Comment: For the use of *il y a* & *depuis* possible duplicate http://french.stackexchange.com/q/6910/358  And you cannot use both *il y a* and *depuis*, it's either one or the other depending on what you mean.

Comment: Merci @Laure. Alors c'est utile de savoir que on n'utilise jamais les deux au même temps. Mais je crois que la question indiquée ne répond pas à ma question précise - c'est à dire: comment est-ce on traduit en français la phrase "It is 10 years ago that we got married"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'anglais s'écrit souvent dans l'ordre inverse du Français

*Nous nous sommes mariés il y a 10 ans*

(we got married) [it's] (10 years ago)

Cependant, il est possible de traduire d'une façon plus littérale :

*Cela fait 10 ans que nous nous sommes mariés*

Ou pour insister sur la durée :

*Cela fait maintenant 10 ans que nous nous sommes mariés*

Ou pour indiquer une action brève ou révolue, sans lien avec l'énonciation on peut employer le passé simple (très rare à l'oral) :

*nous nous mariâmes il y a dix ans*

Comment: Merci beaucoup @Benjamin